# Simulate a selection in a <select> element

Tags: angular, karma-runner

in a angular reactive form I use a simple select element:

```html
<select class="form-control" formControlName="item" id="item" [value]="form.get('item').value">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.key">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

I want to simulate an element being chosen in a unit test:

```
(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('option[value="item2"]')).nativeElement as HTMLElement).click();
```

The selection works, it's the good element (I can change it's attribute for example), but the click does not work. I've try to preselect the  element:

```
(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select')).nativeElement as HTMLElement).click();
```

but still nothing. I've try also to call triggerEventHandler directly on the DebugElement instead of the nativeElement, with "item2" as a param.

So I'm a little out of option.

Thanks

Comment: Update:  fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select')).nativeElement.value = 'item2'; Seem to select a value, but does not trigger the event which binds it to the FormControl value.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
let hl:HTMLSelectElement = (fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('select')).nativeElement as HTMLSelectElement);
hl.value='newvalue'; //set the new value
hl.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); //this is what triggers angular to do its magic 
fixture.detectChanges(); 
tick(); //assuming you are doing this inside a fakeAsync
```

c